# Removing spaces from char with pointer

Tags: c

I'm trying to remove empty spaces from a char with pointer.

```
 char * byte="a b c d"
 char * CopiedByte;
 for (;*byte;++byte)
   {
    if(*byte!=' ')
      *CopiedByte=*byte;


  }
 printf("%s",CopiedByte);
```

But i dont get anything in output

Comment: You have a pointer `CopiedByte`, but *where does it point?!*

Comment: Also, don't forget that `char` strings in  are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. That *null-terminator* is really important for all functions handling strings. If you forget it then string functions will go out of bounds looking for it.

Comment: Please show a [MCVE].

Comment: So which is the easiest way? To use char array instead pointer?

Comment: Lastly, you never change where `CopiedByte` points, so you will overwrite the same location over and over.

Comment: your code doesn't compile .... missing at least ";" at the end of the first line.

Comment: @Dim _To use char array instead pointer?_: it doesn't matter it's very similar. But your problem is not about using pointers or arrays, it's about your code being wrong (see previous comments) and your code being incomplete. You need to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You have not allocated memory to `CopiedByte` and once you copy the char from `byte` to `CopiedByte` you need to increment the `CopiedByte` to point to next location.
Important note: Once you copy all the data put the `NULL` terminator.

Memory allocated using `malloc`(dynamically) need to be freed otherwise there will be `memory leaks`.

```
 char * byte="a b c d";
 char * CopiedByte = malloc(strlen(byte) +1);
 int i=0;
 for (;*byte;++byte)
   {
    if(*byte!=' ')
    {
      CopiedByte[i]=*byte;
      i++;
    }
  }
  CopiedByte[i] = '\0';

 /* do your work*/

  free(CopiedByte);
```

Comment: But also i can't see anything in output.

Comment: @Dim You will be able to see now.

Comment: Neither now....

Comment: Is it more suiable and easy to use Array in my case? Or it doesnt matter?

Comment: @Dim arrays or pointers, it's a matter of personal preference here.

Comment: What takes more memory? Both have same use?

Comment: @Dim One example is If array is declared inside the function it's scope ends within the function.
Only overhead you need to free the pointer once allocated with pointers.